# Box size $R$ as a thermodynamic variable vs position radius $r$ inside the box

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, differentiation

Titles are difficult but I hope I can do a better job in the text.

I am working with a spherical box where I want to have the box's radius $R$ and temperature at the wall $T$ to be the main thermodynamic variables. For the first law I am only taking into account heat and work, so
$$ dE = TdS - PdV.$$
However, I have the energy $E$ explicitly in terms of a different set of variables, $E=E(R,X_1)$, instead of $E=E(R,T)$. I am not exactly looking for an explicit expression for $E(R,T)$, but rather only looking for its partial derivatives through
\begin{align}
dE &= \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial R} \right)_T dR + \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right)_R dT \\
&= \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial R} \right)_{X_1} dR + \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial X_1} \right)_R dX_1.
\end{align}
This would be straightforward if I had information on $X_1(R,T)$. Which I also do not have. What I do have is an explicit expression for another variable $X_2=X_2(R,T)$.

Ok, so now I only need to relate $X_2$ to $X_1$. These two variables correspond to two functions $x_1(r)$ and $x_2(r)$ evaluated at the wall $r=R$, and I know that inside the box they satisfy
\begin{align}
\frac{dx_1}{dr} &= \frac{f_1(x_1,x_2)}{r} \\
\frac{dx_2}{dr} &= \frac{f_2(x_1,x_2)}{r}.
\end{align}
Here, we can exploit the fact that there is a scale invariance, and we can obtain
$$ f_1^{-1}dx_1 = f_2^{-1} dx_2$$ which is valid everywhere (including $r=R$).
So from here, I have two questions:

**First**. Does this mean I can evaluate the previous identity at $r=R$ and obtain
$\frac{dX_1}{dX_2} = \left. \frac{f_1}{f_2} \right|_{r=R}$?

**Second**. Am I safe to assume that $\left. \frac{dX_2}{dr} \right|_R \neq  \frac{dX_2}{dR}$? Because I know for a fact that $\left( \frac{\partial X_2}{\partial R} \right)_T \neq \left. \frac{dX_2}{dr} \right|_R$.

Please tell me if any additional info is helpful, I tried to keep the problem as summarized as possible but might be losing critical info as a result.

Comment: Why do you want to work with energy, and not with the Helmholtz free energy which has $T$ and $V$, aka $R$, as natural variables?

Comment: I do want to work with the Helmholtz free energy. But I do know the energy $E=E(R,X_1)$, so I am trying to make use of it. Then it is just $F=E-TS$.

Comment: If you are going to use statistical mechanics you do not need the energy. The canonical partition function gives you direct access to free energy. If it is an experimental study, maybe adding some details could help.

Comment: I am not going to use statistical mechanics, and I also want $E(R,T)$ so that I can evaluate the stability through the specific heat. So $\left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right)_R= \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial X_1} \right)_R \left( \frac{\partial X_1}{\partial T} \right)_R.$ But I am not sure at this point if $X_2$ can be completely described by $X_1$, in which case I would be able to replace $dX_1 = f(X_1,X_2) dX_2$ (which is the first question) and easily obtain the specific heat.